# Redirect to view-state afte login success

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflow

I'm using for first time spring security (3.2.0.RELEASE) and spring webflow (2.4.0.RC1).
I have a webflow where there is a view-stat which needs a user authenticated:

```
<view-state id="finish" model="order">
    <secured attributes="ROLE_USER" />
    <on-render>
        <render fragments="body" />
    </on-render>
</view-state>
```

If user is not already authenticated is redirected to a login page. I'm wondering if would be possible: user insert his credentials into login page and if he has success, redirect him to  "finish" view-state again with all information of flow.

It's posible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring security redirections inside and outside of a webflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854332/spring-security-redirections-inside-and-outside-of-a-webflow)

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. In spring-security.xml specify the flow URL in "default-target-url" attribute.

If the URL to your flow is something like **screen/finish**, then the configuration would be like below

```
<http auto-config="true" >      
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=t" 
                default-target-url="screen/finish"                  
            always-use-default-target="true" />
    <!--other configurations -->
</http>
```

Comment: But it will keep model "order"? And If I use default-target-url, all points on my webapp where any user can login will be redirected to flow. I should change my question because actually I want a user can log in without any redirection (so after a successful log through a modal window, user will be redirected to the same page), but inside a flow the expected behavior would be as my previous question.

Comment: When a user login, a new "order" will be created and attached to the view. I assume this is what you would expect to happen. Yes, any user who login will be directed to page specified in `default-target-url`

Comment: That's not exactly what I would. I have some pages where user can login (through a modal window). This logins should not redirect user, instead modal window is closed and actual page is refreshed in order to show the name of logged user. In addition, in my web there is a webflow, in this webflow is where an order is created. As a last view-state of de flow user must be logged in order to save the order. So if user is not logged at this point, I redirect him to a login page. Is user logs in successfully, his order should keep "alive" and user should be redirected to finish view-state

Comment: ok, please explain further. Once the modal window is closed, do you want the flow to kickin?

Comment: So there is a possibility that a user can reach the "finish" view-state without login? And that is where you want to ask the user to login if he/she hasn't logged in before.